# Delphi FMX PaintTo() in different file

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I have a small problem, I'm trying to save a portion of a TLayout (LayoutScale) in an Timage (ImmagineCreata). Being TLayout (LayoutScala) very large I would like to break it in many images 8000x8000, but what I get are many images of correct size but all white and only the first image filled with all the content of the TLayout but climbed on 8000x8000

```
    procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var ImmagineCreata : FMX.Graphics.TBitmap;
    NumImgX, NumImgY, x, y, dimensioneX, dimensioneY : integer;
begin
  if (LayoutScala.Width > 8000) or (LayoutScala.Height > 8000) then
  begin
    //valuta il numero di immagini da fare in x e in y
    NumImgX := 1 + (Round(LayoutScala.Width)  div 8000);
    NumImgY := 1 + (Round(LayoutScala.Height) div 8000);
    //salva le immagini
    for y := 1 to NumImgY do
    begin
      //dimensione lato in y
      dimensioneY := 8000;
      if (y = NumImgY) then dimensioneY := Round((NumImgY * 8000) - LayoutScala.Height);
      //valuta l'altro verso
      for x := 1 to NumImgX do
      begin
        //dimensione lato in x
        dimensioneX := 8000;
        if (x = NumImgX) then dimensioneX := Round((NumImgX * 8000) - LayoutScala.Width);
        // Crea il rettangolo di disegno con le dimensioni dell'immagine
        ImmagineCreata := FMX.Graphics.TBitmap.Create(dimensioneX, dimensioneY);
        ImmagineCreata.Clear(TAlphaColorRec.White);
        ImmagineCreata.Canvas.BeginScene;
        //Traccia il controllo e i suoi figli nel bitmap di destinazione
        try LayoutScala.PaintTo(ImmagineCreata.Canvas, RectF((x-1)*8000, (y-1)*8000, ((x-1)*8000)+dimensioneX, ((y-1)*8000)+dimensioneY));
        finally ImmagineCreata.Canvas.EndScene;
        end;
        // Salva l'immagine
        ImmagineCreata.SaveToFile('C:\Immagine'+x.ToString+'.'+y.ToString+'.jpg');
        //svuota la memoria
        ImmagineCreata.Free;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

[image]

I use Delphi 10.2.3 and FireMonkey

Comment: 8000×8000 pixel size image is already very big. I'd cut it to smaller pieces. For example many map application creators use 256×256 pixels size images.

Comment: Please, never post code as an image. It's totally useless waste.

Comment: But what could be the solution?

Answer (score 0):

In your line 
    `try LayoutScala.PaintTo(ImmagineCreata.Canvas..)` 
I believe you misunderstand the `TLayout.PaintTo(ACanvas, ARect)` method. 
**ARect** specifies the rectangle area of the **ACanvas** (destination) to draw on and not the rectangle in the source canvas.

Because you write all squares (with exception of the first one x=1, y=1) outside of the target bitmap you got just white bitmaps for all other x and y combinations.

In order the get the result you want you need to copy first the entire layout to a intermediated bitmap (with the same size as your TLayout) and use inside the nested for loops for x and y the method `Bitmap.Canvas.DrawBitmap` which allows you to handover the source and destination rectangles.

Comment: I can not pass the TLayout in a TBitmap because the TBitmap is larger than 10000x10000 and therefore can not be created

Comment: In general firemonkey limits TBitmap size to 65536 x 65536 pixels but on  Windows platform DirectX limits farther the TBitmap size to 8192 x 8192 pixels. I don't see an alternative way to fetch only a partial rectangle out of a canvas. The method ´TControl.PaintTo´ redirects the canvas and calls the PaintInternal method which paints always the entire area. in opposite to the VCL TCanvas the firemonkey TCanvas does not offer the property pixels to access pixel by pixel at least. That is why you have to think about another structure of your application. How you fill the layout?

Answer (score -1):

I solved by automatically moving the scroll and creating screenshots